# Automatic change searchd.production.pid ownership to desired owner after Sphinx restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, capistrano

I have two users in my server: `root` and `development`. Everytime Sphinx is restarted, the ownership of `searchd.production.pid` always changed to `root`. I always use the `development` to do any cap, update code, etc. though.

I have this in my `deploy.rb`:

```
after "deploy:update_code", "sphinx:stop"
after "deploy:migrate", "sphinx:start"

namespace :sphinx do
  desc "Start Sphinx Searchd"
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current/; /usr/bin/rake ts:start RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end

  desc "Stop Sphinx Searchd"
  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current/; /usr/bin/rake ts:stop RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
  desc "Restart Sphinx Searchd"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{deploy_to}/current/; /usr/bin/rake ts:restart RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end
```

But then this is run using `development` user, I can only change the ownership of a file if I am the owner. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a capistrano issue but SSH.

I guess you are running capistrano from the same server to which you are deploying.

It doesn't matter what user do you use to run 'cap', what it really matters is what user you are if you 'ssh' to your server.

If you are 'development' user and ssh to your server, what user are you ?

root?, then fix your .ssh/config file.

Your deploy.rb looks good, but I would DRY it with:

```
namespace :sphinx do
  desc "Start Sphinx Searchd"
  task :start, :roles => :app do
    rake "ts:start"
  end

  desc "Stop Sphinx Searchd"
  task :stop, :roles => :app do
    rake "ts:stop"
  end
  desc "Restart Sphinx Searchd"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    rake "ts:restart"
  end
end

def rake(rake_task)
  if rake_task
    raise "Rails environment not set" unless rails_env
    run "cd #{current_path} && rake #{rake_task} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end
```